# Calculus Curve Derivative Lemma

Tags: calculus, vectors

[image]

I'm reading [this textbook](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP4/clp_4_vc_text.pdf). I don't quite understand this lemma on page 6, specifically (b) and (c). Let's start with an example provided in the text. [image]

I don't understand how the following is derived: $\frac{ds(\theta)}{d\theta} = |\textbf{r'}(\theta)|$

Can we start with that?

Comment: It is not specially *derived* in the example. According to the text, it is just taken from the lemma, part (b). You are likely to understand how it is derived if you read the proof of the lemma.

Comment: That's the problem. There is no proof to the lemma, as long as I can tell.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. $$\frac{ds(\theta)}{d\theta} = |\textbf{r}'(\theta)|$$ would that equality make sense if instead of $\theta$ we had $t$? or is this not what you are asking?

Comment: The lemma is a summary of some conceptual discussion before that, on pp. 4-5. You may also look at [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-advanced-functions-new/bc-9-3/v/parametric-curve-arc-length). The formal way to prove it is to use Riemann sums and take the limit.